# ignite delete row issue

Tags: sql-delete, ignite

I create a table user(_key(user_id,type),user_id(int),type(string),name(string), and had row,(1,"2","Scott") , then I update the row values to (2,"2","admin").and then delete the row delete from user where user_id = 2 and type = "2",sql scripts executed successfully, but select * from user again, the row still there ,ignite version number 2.9.1.anybody has the issue.

Comment: Might want to paste your exact SQL statements so it's clear. Don't know how you changed the PK (user_id from 1 to 2). My 2.9.1 test:
`> create table user (user_id int, type VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, PRIMARY key(user_id,type));
> INSERT INTO user (user_id, type, name) VALUES (1, '2', 'Scott');
> select * from user;
|  USER_ID   |  TYPE   |   NAME   |
| 1               | 2           | Scott       |
> update user set user_id=2, name='Admin' where user_id=1 and type='2';`
**Error: SQL UPDATE can't modify key or its fields directly (state=42000,code=2003)**

Answer (score 1):

Ignite doesn't support a primary key modification. As result, you're not able to change the "user_id" value since it's a part of the PK. As a workaround, you can remove the existing row and insert a new one with the updated value.